# MVC asp.NET multiple buttons with no name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to check which button as caused post back in the controllfer action. 
My problem is I am using two buttons with no name attribute. 
How can i check which button has clicked when button is not having name attribute 
Please advice

Edit : I can't give name attribute as i am using button controls created by internal framework in that they don't have name attribute. 
So is there any alternative for it.

I know there is one way putting those buttons in different form tags but i want to check for different options thanks

Comment: Why can't you give your button a name attribute?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there is no way to check which button caused the form to be submitted without giving it a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give your button a name attribute the you could simply do..

```
<input ... name="MyBtn" .../>

If (Request.Form["MyBtn"] != null) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC will check that for you. The submit button is connected to the Action which has the same name as the View.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Id">Id:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Id") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Id", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Thema">Thema:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Thema") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Thema", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

In the Controller you use HttpVerbs for the Get and the Post

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Add(ThemaWebSites thema)
        {
            return View(thema);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID attribute if you don't want to use a name, then use the "value" attribute:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="OK" />
<button type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel" />
```

You need a name, otherwise it won't show up in the `Request.Form` or `FormCollection` and you won't be able to access the values.

**Edit**: if you *really* can't use name or ID attributes, you might be forced to use some JavaScript trickery so that each button sets the value of a hidden field on their `onclick` event...

Comment: I'm kinda curious to know why not? What's the restriction?